# Knockout binds element with [object HTMLDivElement] intermittently

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs, knockout-3.0

I am using requireJs+knockout js in my UI application.

I have a div element in my main html file (index.html) like:

```
<html style="height:100%" lang="en">
  <head>
     <title>Main</title>
     <script data-main="myMain" src="/path/js/libs/require/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body  style="background-color:#EDEDED">
        <div class="someClass" id="loading" data-bind="text:loading"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am binding it to a "Loading" text in my myMain.js file with:

```
ko.applyBindings({loading: getTranslatedStringFromLib('LOADING')}, $('#loading')[0]);
```

While this works fine in 9 out of 10 cases, occasionaly knockout injects the div with `[object HTMLDivElement]`, making the generated code look like:

```
<div data-bind="text:loading" class="someClass" id="loading">[object HTMLDivElement]</div>
```

Has anyone seen something like this before? Any help with what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because you have an element with the id `loading`, and when (for some reason) the view-model isn't available (or is changing), it resolved the `loading` token as `window.loading` which [references](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object) your `#loading` element.

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ancdbv0k/) (for example)

Comment: Under what scenario might that [view-model isn't available (or is changing)] happen? From har files its clear that the myMain.js file has been downloaded.

Comment: If you're re-applying the model and it doesn't contain the `loading` property, it will fallback to `window.loading`. Also, it might be that your `getTranslatedStringFromLib()` function is the culprit. Show its code if you think it's relevant.